# Codeigniter ZIP file download corrupted

Tags: php, codeigniter, zip

I Am using the standard CI zip library to read a directory and create a zip file for downloading however when I am testing this in windows I get:

[image: Windows Error]

and in OS X the zip unpacks a cpgz file which then unpacks to a zip file - infinitely

My CI function:

```
public function downloadPackage($unique) {
    $this->load->library('zip');
    $text = $this->syndication_m->getTextForContent($unique);

    $path = '/var/www/html/uploads/'.$unique.'/';

    if(file_exists($path."copy-".$unique.".txt")) {
        unlink($path."copy-".$unique.".txt");
        $fp = fopen($path."copy-".$unique.".txt","wb");
        fwrite($fp,$text);
        fclose($fp);
    }

    $this->zip->read_dir($path);
    $this->zip->download('dl-'.$unique.'.zip');
}
```

Can anyone help me with a fix or suggest what to do here? Thanks

**EDIT**

```
public function downloadPackage($unique) {
    $this->load->library('zip');
    $path = '/var/www/html/uploads/'.$unique.'/';

    $text = $this->syndication_m->getTextForContent($unique);
    $this->zip->read_dir($path, TRUE);
    $this->zip->add_data('copy-'.$unique.'.txt', $text->synd_text);
    $this->zip->download('dl-'.$unique.'.zip');
}
```

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/111977/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what i know and what [codeigniter's documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/zip.html) is saying:

`$path = '/var/www/html/uploads/'.$unique.'/';`

- **`$this->zip->read_dir($path)`**

  *Permits you to compress a folder (and its contents) that already exists somewhere on your server. Supply a file path to the directory and the zip class will **recursively** read it and recreate it as a Zip archive. **All files contained within the supplied path** will be encoded, as will **any sub-folders contained within it**.*

Basically you are creating a zip with everything starting from `/var` and ending with the files in the `$unique` folder, something is bound to be wrong ...

I recommend setting the second parameter to false, as the documentation specifies:

*`If you want the tree preceding the target folder to be ignored you can pass FALSE (boolean) in the second parameter.`*

- **`$this->zip->read_dir($path, FALSE)`**

  *This will create a ZIP with the folder "`$unique`" inside, then all sub-folders stored correctly inside that, but **will not include** the folders `/var/www/html/uploads`.*

I also suggest/recommend, for better control of data and i believe fewer resources, to use:

- `$this->zip->add_data()` instead of `fopen()` and `$this->zip->read_dir()`

Example:

```
public function downloadPackage($unique) {
    $this->load->library('zip');

    $text = $this->syndication_m->getTextForContent($unique);

    $this->zip->add_data('copy-'.$unique.'.txt', $text);
    $this->zip->download('dl-'.$unique.'.zip');
}
```

**NOTE**: *Do not display any data in the controller in which you call this function since it sends various server headers that cause the download to happen and the file to be treated as binary.*

--------------- EDIT ---------------

Unless you want to add to the zip whatever files are in the `$unuqie` directory, there is no use for `$this->zip->read_dir()`.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Testing extends CI_Controller {
    public function downloadPackage($unique = '') {
        $this->load->library('zip');

        $unique = '4ts5yegq;';
        $text = 'I am zorro ...';

        $this->zip->add_data('copy-'.$unique.'.txt', $text);
        $this->zip->download('dl-'.$unique.'.zip');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi I have just tried all of this an still not working correctly.

Comment: i also tried the example that i gave you and worked as expected. Can you please show what is the value of `$unique` and what `$this->syndication_m->getTextForContent()` is returning!?

Comment: $unique = 4ts5yegq; and text is equal to a string of text I have made a change here to $text->synd_text;

Comment: Updated my question with a new snippet as per your answer

Comment: please try the function in my edit, just copy/paste, and let me know if it works properly ...

Comment: Copied yours and still the same problem

Answer (score 10):

I have just come across a very similar issue where the downloaded zip file got corrupted and this is what solved my problem:

I call the `ob_end_clean()` function just before the `$this->zip->download()` line.

Comment: Works brilliantly. ob_end_clean == "clean/clear output buffer"

Comment: This only happend when I created big ZIP files (more than 250 files, 50MB), using ob_end_clean() solved the issue. Thanks Peter!

Answer (score 0):

In place of writing file using fopen try to use "$this->zip->add_data($text);" and make sure directory(sub directories) $path pointing to does not have any soft link(shortcuts) files.

Apart from this try, not to include empty folders in zip file sometimes it creates these kind of issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. whenever i was creating new zip file and unzipping **.zip** file, new file was creating as **.cpgz**. this was happening due to my zip file was not creating properly. Means it was creating as corrupt zip file.

Meanwhile i was getting **Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes)** error. Once i solved this Fetal error, my zip and unzip issue got resolved.

I resolved below error

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 262144 bytes)

Add into index.php

> **ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');**

Answer (score 0):

deletes the topmost output buffer and all of its contents using the  ob_end_clean() function. Add ob_end_clean(); function just before db download function call.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).